# how can I show the UIDatePicker in Swift after user presses a button?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

In my `swift` app I have three components: a `textview`, a `button` and a `label`. Currently I handle keyboard behavior, so when user starts typing anything in the `textview` (or rather - just taps it), the keyboard appears. I handle it with the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
           #selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame),
           name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
}
```

and then the method `keyboardWillChangeFrame` I have:

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification) {
    let endFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    if(isKeyboardShown == true)
    {
        bottomConstraint.constant = view.bounds.height - endFrame.origin.y
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        isKeyboardShown = false
    } else {
        bottomConstraint.constant = view.bounds.height - endFrame.origin.y
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        isKeyboardShown = true
    }

}
```

that works fine. I want to do the same with the constraints while showing date picker - when user presses the button the picker should appear where normally keyboard appears (so the screen moves up while showing picker on the bottom) and then the label could show the selected date.

Can you help me with that? I added already outlet for the button action:

```
@IBAction func datePickerButtonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date

    textView.inputView = datePickerView

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapViewController.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

}
```

and

```
func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    //dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.MediumStyle

    //dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.NoStyle

    //print(dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date))

}
```

but nothing happens, the button doesn't make the picker appear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The button changes the input view of the text view. It doesn't make the text view first responder. Try touching inside the text view and the date picker should appear instead of the normal keyboard.

Comment: hm but I would like to avoid this situation - of course if it's possible - so when user presses the textview then the keyboard appears, and when user presses the button - the datepicker appears... is that possible?

Comment: You can use `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` to show the keyboard, and either set `textView.inputView = nil` (to change back to normal keyboard), or `textView.resignFirstResponder()` to close the keyboard.

Comment: hmm this line `textView.inputView = nil` throws me an error that inputView is get-only property. And I cannot use `resignFirstResponder` because then my notification for hiding the keyboard fires and the screen goes back down...